# Tensorflow in Android: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I have a problem with importing Tensorflow model into Android Studio application.
I have built a model, froze the model and optimized that frozen model in Python, and now I'm trying to use it in the Android app, but it constantly returns me that same error that I must feed a value for a placeholder. This is happening in the Android app when I run **inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);** function.

I don't know if the error is it in the model itself, but I'm assuming that python would throw me an error and won't build the model, what he did.

This is the example of rows of data I'm sending to Tensorflow (in csv file):

```
1,26,2091,5,2,0,0,0,0,0,85,105,6,4,0,1
1,26,47,9,4,0,0,0,0,0,85,0,7,4,1,0
```

This is the creating model in Python:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from math import floor, ceil
from pylab import rcParams


columns = ["Gender", "Age", "StepsNum", "Still", "ContinuousStill",
           "Running", "Driving", "Cycling", "Weather", "TargetWeight",
           "Calories", "DayOfTheWeek", "PartOfTheDay",
           "NotificationType", "UserInput"]

userinput = ['0','1']


activites_df = pd.read_csv("E:\\MASTER\\PythonPrograms\\useractivityInt.csv", header = None, names=columns)


#encode all strings
def encode(series): 
    #print(pd.get_dummies(series.astype(str)))
    return pd.get_dummies(series.astype(str))


train_x = pd.DataFrame(activites_df, columns = columns, dtype=float)
# train_x = activites_df
train_y = encode(activites_df.UserInput)
print(train_y)
# train_y = activites_df.iloc[:,-1]
# print(train_y)
# train_y = pd.DataFrame(userinput, dtype=float)


train_size = 0.9

train_cnt = floor(train_x.shape[0] * train_size)
#iloc[0] - first row, iloc[:0] - first column of data frame, iloc[0:n] - first n rows
x_train = train_x.iloc[0:train_cnt].values
y_train = train_y.iloc[0:train_cnt].values

x_test = train_x.iloc[train_cnt:].values
y_test = train_y.iloc[train_cnt:].values


def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, keep_prob):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    layer_1 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_1, keep_prob)
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer


#shape[0] - Gives the number of rows in matrix.. shape[1] - numbers of columns 
n_hidden_1 = 38
n_input = train_x.shape[1]
n_classes = train_y.shape[1]
# n_classes = 2

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1]),tf.float32),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_classes]),tf.float32)
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1]),tf.float32),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]),tf.float32)
}

#keep_prob: A scalar Tensor with the same type as x. The probability that each element is kept.
# keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

training_epochs = 5000
display_step = 1000
batch_size = 32

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input], name='input')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

predictions = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)

#_y is name for output node
#If we take an input of [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], the softmax of that is [0.024, 0.064, 0.175, 0.475, 0.024, 0.064, 0.175]. 
# The output has most of its weight where the '4' was in the original input. 
# This is what the function is normally used for: to highlight the largest values and suppress values which are significantly below the maximum value.

pred_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(predictions, name="y_")

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=predictions, labels=y))

LEARNING_RATE = 0.0025

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cost)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.0
        total_batch = int(len(x_train) / batch_size)
        x_batches = np.array_split(x_train, total_batch)
        y_batches = np.array_split(y_train, total_batch)
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = x_batches[i], y_batches[i]
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], 
                            feed_dict={
                                x: batch_x, 
                                y: batch_y, 
                                keep_prob: 0.8
                            })
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "loss=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    print("Optimization Finished!")
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: x_test, y: y_test, keep_prob: 1.0}))

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '.', 'E:\\MASTER\\PythonPrograms\\har.pbtxt')  
    saver.save(sess, save_path = "E:\\MASTER\\PythonPrograms\\har.ckpt")
```

The main parts of the code in Android Studio are those:

Definition of variables:

```
 private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/optimized_frozen_har.pb";

    String INPUT_NODE = "input";
    String[] OUTPUT_NODES = {"y_"};
    String OUTPUT_NODE = "y_";
    //I don't know what is input size
    long[] INPUT_SIZE = {1, 15};
    int OUTPUT_SIZE = 2;

    private TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;
```

Initialization and calling function in OnCreate:

```
inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(appContext.getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);


 float[] data = {(float)1.0, (float)26.0, (float)1000.0, (float)3.0, (float)1.0,(float)0.0, (float) 0.0, (float)0.0, (float)0.0, (float)0.0, (float)85.0, (float)48.0, (float)7.0, (float)4.0, (float)2.0};
        float[] out = predictProbabilitiesFloat(data);
```

Function for returning result from TensorFlow:

```
 public float[] predictProbabilitiesFloat(float[] data) {
        float[] result = new float[OUTPUT_SIZE];
        inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE, data, INPUT_SIZE);
        inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);
        inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE, result);

        //for us it should be 0 or 1
        return result;
    }
```

If somebody knows how to fix this problem, please help me, I have few more days to finish this as one part of my master thesis.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I managd to solve my own issue with friends help... So if anyone else has the same problem, here is the solution:

The new model looks like this:

```
# from __future__ import absolute_import
# from __future__ import division
# from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from math import floor, ceil
from pylab import rcParams


columns = ["Gender", "Age", "StepsNum", "Still", "ContinuousStill",
           "Running", "Driving", "Cycling", "Sleeping", "Weather", "TargetWeight",
           "Calories", "DayOfTheWeek", "PartOfTheDay",
           "NotificationType", "UserInput"]

columns_train = ["Gender", "Age", "StepsNum", "Still", "ContinuousStill",
           "Running", "Driving", "Cycling", "Sleeping", "Weather", "TargetWeight",
           "Calories", "DayOfTheWeek", "PartOfTheDay",
           "NotificationType"]

userinput = [0,1]


activites_df = pd.read_csv("E:\\MASTER\\PythonPrograms\\useractivityInt.csv", header = None, names=columns, dtype=float)

#encode all strings
def encode(series): 
    #print(pd.get_dummies(series.astype(str)))
    return pd.get_dummies(series.astype(str))

def to_float(series):
    return pd.to_numeric(series, downcast='float')

mydict_gender = {"Male": 1, "Female": 2}
mydict_weather = {"Cloudy": 1, "Clear": 2, "Foggy": 3, "Rainy": 4, "Snowy": 5, "Icy": 6}
mydict_partOfTheDay = {"Morning": 1, "Noon": 2, "Afternoon": 3, "Evening": 4, "Night": 5}
mydict_notificationType = {"atHome": 1, "doExercises": 2, "goToBed": 3, "getUp": 4, "goToCycling": 5, "goToRunning": 6, "goToWork": 7, "StepsGoal": 8, "takeAWalk": 9}

#treba da bude matrica!             
train_x = pd.DataFrame(activites_df, columns = columns_train, dtype=float)

# train_x = activites_df
train_y = encode(activites_df.UserInput)
# train_y = activites_df.iloc[:,-1]
# print(train_y)
# train_y = pd.DataFrame(userinput, dtype=float)


train_size = 0.9

#floor - zaokruzivanje.. tran_cnt je broj podataka u csvu
train_cnt = floor(train_x.shape[0] * train_size)
#iloc[0] - first row, iloc[:0] - first column of data frame, iloc[0:n] - first n rows
x_train = train_x.iloc[0:train_cnt].values
y_train = train_y.iloc[0:train_cnt].values

#uzmi neki tamo milioniti red i njegove vrednosti za test
x_test = train_x.iloc[train_cnt:].values
y_test = train_y.iloc[train_cnt:].values


def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, keep_prob):
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    layer_1 = tf.nn.dropout(layer_1, keep_prob)
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer


#shape[0] - Gives the number of rows in matrix.. shape[1] - numbers of columns 
n_hidden_1 = 38
n_input = train_x.shape[1]
n_classes = train_y.shape[1]

weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1]),tf.float32),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_classes]),tf.float32)
}

biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1]),tf.float32),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]),tf.float32)
}

#keep_prob: A scalar Tensor with the same type as x. The probability that each element is kept.
# keep_prob = tf.placeholder("float")
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="keep_prob")

training_epochs = 5000
display_step = 1000
batch_size = 32

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input], name='input')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

#input_size doesnt exist
# print("input size: " + n_input.train_size)
predictions = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases, keep_prob)

#_y is name for output node
#If we take an input of [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], the softmax of that is [0.024, 0.064, 0.175, 0.475, 0.024, 0.064, 0.175]. 
# The output has most of its weight where the '4' was in the original input. 
# This is what the function is normally used for: to highlight the largest values and suppress values which are significantly below the maximum value.
pred_softmax = tf.nn.softmax(predictions, name="y_")

#cost is loss
#ovo je loss funkcija
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=predictions, labels=y))

LEARNING_RATE = 0.0025

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cost)

total_batch = int(len(x_train) / batch_size)

x_batches = []
y_batches = []

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
for i in range(total_batch):
    x_batches.append([])
    y_batches.append([])
    for j in range(batch_size):
        x_batches[i].append(x_train[batch_size*i + j])
        y_batches[i].append(y_train[batch_size*i + j])

#x_batches = np.array_split(x_train, total_batch)
#y_batches = np.array_split(y_train, total_batch)
#print("{}, {}, {}".format(len(x_batches), len(x_batches[0]), len(x_batches[0][0])))
#print("{}, {}, {}".format(len(y_batches), len(y_batches[0]), len(y_batches[0][0])))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.0
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = x_batches[i], y_batches[i]
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost],
                            feed_dict={
                                x: batch_x, 
                                y: batch_y, 
                                keep_prob: 0.8
                            })
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "loss=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
    print("Optimization Finished!")
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: x_test, y: y_test, keep_prob: 1.0}))

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, '.', 'E:\\MASTER\\PythonPrograms\\har.pbtxt')  
    saver.save(sess, save_path = "E:\\MASTER\\PythonPrograms\\har.ckpt")
    # sess.close()
```

And the android method for calling TensorFlow method looks like this:

```
 public float[] predictProbabilitiesFloat(float[] data) {
        float[] result = new float[OUTPUT_SIZE];
        inferenceInterface.feed(INPUT_NODE, data, INPUT_SIZE);
        float[] kprob = {(float) 1.0};
        inferenceInterface.feed("keep_prob", kprob, 1);
        inferenceInterface.run(OUTPUT_NODES);
        inferenceInterface.fetch(OUTPUT_NODE, result);

        //for us it should be 0 or 1
        return result;
    }
```

I needed to feed keep_prob value through Android app also...

I hope that this will help someone...